# What is the missing word in this analogy? (7 letters)

Tags: riddle, word

> **Fibonacci** is to **Sun**

as

> **Spiral** is to ???????

Comment: Wait now it's only 7 letters? Make up your mind! -1

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is a sort of

> Asterism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterism_%28astronomy%29)

As,

> Numbers of Fibonacci can be joined (on a number line representation in two dimensions, for example forming squares etc.) to form a **Spiral**.

In a similar fashion,

> Several **suns** (which are basically stars) can form Asterism (which is a subset of usually known constellation) which consists of specific geometric shapes.

Well, based on latest edit/hint, I guess it is

> Eclipse

As,

> It has 7 letters and it is the path that sun takes around *vega*. The analogy taken is the path traversed by / loci of Fibonacci numbers and the sun

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Sombrero?

Because

> **Fibonacci** *sequence* is to **Sun**, a main *sequence* star.
>  as **Spiral** *galaxy* is to **Sombrero**, a spiral *galaxy*.

Kind of a stretch I suppose...

Answer (score -3):

My answer is....

> universe

Since:

> Fibonacci is to sun as spiral is to universe.
>
> Sun is to galaxy what  galaxy is to universe
>
> Sun is to spiral what Fibonacci is to galaxy
>
> This can continue but they all check out in terms of relativity to one another

Comment: Fibonacci = sun

Comment: It's hard to follow the reasoning behind these relations. Could you kindly explain how you came up with this answer?

Comment: I could but if you are unable to follow that analogy, then the explanation would probably be of no use. The answer has multiple answers relative to how you view each piece of the system being compared. Universe is the only 8 letter word I could come up with right away that was one of those answers

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see that I posted that comment of Fibonacci = sun the comparison got to a point that to explain it through text may not have been easy to understand and people would have just said I was wrong so I didn't post the rest